# Multiple checkboxes controling pivot table filters

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a user friendly pivot table control. I have multiple macros set up to control the pivot table like so:

```
Sub FilterA()
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("A").CurrentPage = "TRUE"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("B").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("C").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("D").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("E").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("F").CurrentPage = "(All)"
End Sub

Sub FilterB()
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("A").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("B").CurrentPage = "TRUE"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("C").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("D").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("E").CurrentPage = "(All)"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("F").CurrentPage = "(All)"
End Sub
```

and so on...

What I want to do is be able to append these to check boxes, but be able to tick off multiple boxes for multiple filters. (A and C for instance) I realize I cannot do this using the method above. Is there any way I can? I feel like I am missing something. Please keep in mind I'm not very proficient in vba.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the checkboxes `OnAction` method to run a macro when clicked. Or you can loop through the checkboxes in your code and if the values is `True` apply a certain filter.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm fairly inexperienced with vba, but I will try to look for more info based on your suggestions.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2010 you should take a look at slicers. No VBA required.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic syntax is like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseCheckBox()

Dim cb as Checkbox

Set cb = Sheets(1).Controls("myCheckbox")

If cb.Value = True

      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("A").CurrentPage = "TRUE"

End If

End Sub
```

You can expand this to add as many checkboxes as you want, loop through them, change conditions, etc.